# Reformatting a javascript function for printing

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

So, deciding to be right on the edges of my competency, I have decided to give Nashorn a try, because I have a use case where it would be useful to allow user the ability to write their own filters for a Java app.

I can pretty much make everything work end to end (web page with textarea -> saved Couchbase object -> script engine within Java), but for the UI piece I would like to be able to prettify/format the user defined text field (not necessarily in real time, but maybe upon saving).

I originally thought it would be relatively simple to use JSON.stringify, but apparently life isn't that convenient.  Is there a javascript native/library based approach to taking the string representation of a function and applying lipstick to my user generated pigs?

Dave

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbeautifier.org library will format your javascript functions.  JSON.stringify 3rd argument allows you to pretty up your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) module that does the beautifying at http://jsbeautifier.org. Usage:

```
var beautifiedJsString = js_beautify('[YourJsString]', options);
```

List of options [here](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify#options).